# Why is Request.BodyReader empty, when I add request parameters (ASP.NET Core 3.0)

Tags: c#, async-await, asp.net-core-3.0

I migrate from ASP.NET Core 2.2 to 3.0 and now have a problem. If I write code like this:

```
[HttpPost("test")]
public async Task Test(object o) {
    HttpContext.Request.EnableBuffering();
    var result = await HttpContext.Request.BodyReader.ReadAsync();
    var buffer = result.Buffer;
    Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer.FirstSpan));
    HttpContext.Request.BodyReader.AdvanceTo(buffer.End);
}
```

I will receive an empty message in console, but if I remove parameter

```
[HttpPost("test")]
public async Task Test() {
    HttpContext.Request.EnableBuffering();
    var result = await HttpContext.Request.BodyReader.ReadAsync();
    var buffer = result.Buffer;
    Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer.FirstSpan));
    HttpContext.Request.BodyReader.AdvanceTo(buffer.End);
}
```

, I receive message from body

> curl -X POST \
>     http://localhost:5000/test \
>     -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
>       -d '{
>         "test":123
>       }'

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem in my middleware. Have you found a solution?

Comment: Look my issue https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/15009

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem, logging request bodies for webhook request bodies.

You need to first enable buffering for the request body, otherwise, it is a forward-only stream, which when consumed will be empty (and cannot be rewound).

In Startup.cs, add the following to the Configure() method:

```
app.Use((context, next) =>
        {
            context.Request.EnableBuffering();
            return next();
        });
```

I found the solution here: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/15009#issuecomment-542291956 (Thratcher wrote it)